# Narrowing, unevaluated context and template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype, narrowing

Consider the following code:

```
auto f() -> decltype(int{0.}, void()) { }
int main() { f(); }
```

It doesn't compile (as expected) with an error:

> narrowing conversion of '0.0' from 'double' to 'int' inside { }

Both GCC and clang agree on that.
Now consider the code below:

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T) -> decltype(int{0.}, void()) { }

int main(){
    f(0);
}
```

In this case, clang 3.9 returns an error and GCC 6.2 compiles with no errors.

Is there any reason for which the narrowing conversion should be accepted in case of a function template or is it an error of GCC?

---

I'm going to open an issue to GCC for I guess it should fail to compile, but I would like to know if I'm missing something important about function template here.

Comment: Definite GCC bug, although without that use of `f` it would be ill-formed NDR.

Comment: @T.C. I don't get it. Why would it be ill-formed?

Comment: [\[temp.res\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8), as usual.

Comment: Now all compilers issue an error with your second template example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8vPjqffTs